# How can I set a DatePicker's date to yesterday?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, datepicker

This:

```
dtpFrom.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now -1;
```

(which is how it was done in Delphi), does not work; I get, *"Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'int'"*

Update: OK, I see I can do this, although I don't know if this is the most succinct way:

```
    int dtYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    int dtMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int dtDay = DateTime.Now.Day;

    dtpFrom.SelectedDate = new DateTime(dtYear, dtMonth, dtDay - 1);
```

...and now I see there is a better way, but must wait a minute before selecting a correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dtpFrom.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
dtpFrom.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes here and wanted to make the text to show yesterday default use

DatePickerName**.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);**